# Tengo problemas con este formulario

Tags: javascript

cada vez que envió el evento no guardar el valor, si lo guarda en el localstorage, pero lo que quiero hacer es mostrar los elementos por pantallas, estoy haciendo la prueba primero con un console.log y veo que el mensaje aparece un segundo y desaparece.

```js
var formulario = document.querySelector("form")[0]
    
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    
      console.log("hola")
     var platillos = document.querySelector("#plato")
    
     localStorage.setItem(platillos, platillos)
    
    })
```

```html
<form action="">
        
        <input id = "plato" type="text" name="comida">
        <button type= "submit">enviar</button>
    
    
    
      </form>
```

Comment: ¿No te muestra fallo de Javascript en la consola?

Comment: no, muestra el hola por un segundo y desaparece

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas varios archivos JavaScript enlazados a esa pagina?

Comment: no solo es un archivo js

Comment: Pues entonces ya no se que decirte, es que esta mañana se me ha dado el caso que tenia en una web dos ficheros javascript y el que me daba el fallo era el primero al que estaba manipulando, el segundo,  y no me había dado cuenta y al ejecutarse el primero y después el segundo, este último me borraba la consola, por eso te pregunte si tenias dos ficheros distintos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te ocurre porque siempre (por defecto) que se hace el submit de un formulario este recarga la página y pierdes los logs de la consola. Para evitar este comportamiento puedes usar el método [e.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```
var formulario = document.querySelector("form")

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("hola")
  var platillos = document.querySelector("#plato")

  localStorage.setItem(platillos, platillos)

})
```

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar mas información sobre ese método e.preventDefault o algún enlace?  Gracias.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho, ya esta solucionado

Comment: de nada. Acepta la respuesta si te sirvió para que le sirva a los demas :)